# Calling login function in main.dart flutter

Tags: function, flutter, dart

I have a login page named login.dart and in this flie I have signin() function I want to call this function in my main.dart

any idea??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create simple dart class separate file define static or normal signin() function in that class.

after that Call that function whenever you need. It is simple and easy way to modularize your functionality and reusability.

You can pass variables as a parameters also.

**main.dart**

```
void main() {
  MyClass().signin();
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

**myClass.dart**

```
class MyClass {
  ....
  void signin(){
  ....
  /* signin logic */
  }

}
```

In login.dart file you can also use this signin() function.

Comment: sorry just one thing..if my function in _LogInstate how can i call it ?

Comment: It's private method you can't access it out side of class.
Simply remove "_" from method name.
rename it "loginState".

Comment: in dart programming "_" at beginning it's make method or variable as a private.
Private variable and method can be accessible inside the class not outside of it.

Answer (score 0):

```
void main() {
  Login().signin();
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.